# Duplicate entries when using JOIN and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, database, database-schema, forum

I'm trying to make a query for "pagination", basically joining the user table with the threads and posts table to display the forum page (with the threads in range) it's supposed to be sorted by the last post inside each thread. The problems I'm facing are either:

- threads get duplicated
- takes too long to complete
- The user ID of the LAST post is the same as the thread author id (in this case the thread aren't duplicated)

This is the query I'm currently using

```
SELECT
t.TId AS thread_id,
t.TName AS thread_name,
t.TAuthorId AS thread_author_id,
u2.UName AS thread_author_name,
t.TDeleted AS thread_deleted_boolean,

/* This might slow down things */
(SELECT COUNT(forum_posts.PId) FROM forum_posts WHERE forum_posts.TId = t.TId) AS thread_posts,
(SELECT CEIL(COUNT(forum_posts.PId) / 20) FROM forum_posts WHERE forum_posts.TId = t.TId) AS thread_pages,
/* This might slow down things */


p.PId AS lastpost_id,
FROM_UNIXTIME(p.PDate/1000) AS lastpost_date,
p.PAuthorId AS lastpost_author_id,
u.UName AS lastpost_author_name

FROM forum_posts AS p

LEFT JOIN forum_threads AS t
ON t.TId = p.TId

/*
* Not used
LEFT JOIN forum_users AS u
ON t.TAuthorId = u.UId OR p.PAuthorId = u.UId
*/

LEFT JOIN forum_users AS u
ON p.PAuthorId = u.UId

LEFT JOIN forum_users AS u2
ON t.TAuthorId = u2.UId

ORDER BY p.PId DESC
LIMIT 50
```

This one is relatively fast, the thread author id and the lastpost author id are different and work just fine, the problem is that the threads are shown multiple times (duplicated). I've tried adding a

```
GROUP BY t.TId
```

near the end but it just makes the query never finish loading.

Is this a indexing problem?

It's worth noting that it would be nice if I could change what I order by and what I limit by dynamically...

```
query += `LIMIT ` + ((page - 1) * (THREADS_SHOWN_PER_PAGE)) + `,` + THREADS_SHOWN_PER_PAGE;
```

Also, it's not a big deal if the user is null, the way I'm inserting things in the database sometimes the user is created after the post/thread.

Answer (score 0):

How to do a forum...

- Materialize last_post_id and post_count in threads table (update them on posting)
- Create an index on (forum_id,last_post_id)

This little bit of denormalization is essential for performance. Without this, it will not work. The index on (forum_id,last_post_id) will allow you to sort threads in each forum by last post, which is what you usually want to display.

Caching post count will greatly speed up your pagination.

And, obviously, since the last page of a topic is the most accessed, you will display posts with ORDER BY post_id DESC when you're accessing a page closer to the end than to the beginning of the topic. Adjust LIMIT values accordingly.

Comment: The thing is that my database isn't exactly a forum, I'm actually scraping another forum and creating a copy of it, that's why sometimes a post will exist but the user will not exist (yet), I don't know how reliable updating the thread every post I fetch would be, especially when I'm getting multiple threads and multiple posts per second, wouldn't that glitch out? like too many queries on the same thing almost in the same second?

Comment: Hm, well in that case it the post count wouldn't be that useful, but you still need the last_post_id. If you don't store it, then you need to compute the last post of each topic prior to sorting them by last post, and this will likely be very slow. If you're worried about concurrent updates, do "UPDATE SET last_post_id=new_value WHERE last_post_id<new_value AND topic_id=..."

Comment: I'll try to do that, if I do it then I can drop one of the "LEFT JOIN on forum_users" and get the username and ID by doing a selection kinda like those two between "/* This might slow down things */" in my query right? like a select on forum_posts WHERE PId = t.last_id? Wouldn't I need two queries still? one to get the post author id from forum_posts  and then another on forum_users using it to get the username?

Comment: Yes, you can join directly on posts as you say, it is standard practice. I recommend not counting the posts in the topic list page, unless not displaying it prevents you from sleeping at night...

Comment: I'll try to do that then, on the subject of indexes I still can't quite wrap my head around them, is there any other index you would recommend?

Comment: A forum is a well-known use case, please post your tables (SHOW CREATE TABLE... or phpmyadmin screenshot) I'll tell you the indexes you need. (put the info in your question) Also if you really want to have an instant-access number of posts, put a post_count in topic and "update set post_count=post_count+1" every time you add a post. You can put it in a trigger too.

Comment: I thought about adding updates like that every added post but the volume of posts per second can get pretty big depending on the forum page I'm indexing. This is my current schema https://pastebin.com/1Ev41g2d. I've yet to update the query on my first post, still modifying the program itself to use the new "TLastPostId" in the forum_threads. You might notice some fields that are supposed to be IDs are varchar, that's because of the problem javascript has with handling big numbers, they have to be strings. I also used to have foreign keys to the user id but I had to remove them.